# Negation of failure in Prolog

Tags: prolog

What is going to be the output, True or False, of the following:

```
The following code implements the negation as failure in Prolog

    not(G).
    not(G) :- G, !, fail.
```

Is it True or False? Can anyone interpret what the second command does, `not(G) :- G, !, fail`. ?

Comment: `!` is not a negation operator, it's the [*cut* operator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Cuts_and_Negation).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, but will it be true or false and why ?

Comment: This depends on how you call it (i.e. what you ass for `G`)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, can you explain what `G, !, fail.` does?

Comment: Your `not` predicate will always succeed on the first call because `not(G).` is true regardless of `G`, and `not(G)` is the first clause in your `not` relation (so it's the first encountered on a query).

Comment: `G, !, fail` will just fail, without backtracking, if G succeeds. The cut prevents backtracking when the fail occurs.

Comment: @John `not(X) ` in prolog  `\+(X) `

Comment: This seems to be an exam question that asks "Is it true that the following code implements negation as failure in Prolog?". The answer is no.